# Training Diffusion Probabilistic Models

Tags: papers, generative-model, image-generation, diffusion-models, markov-chain

My question is in regards to the training process for Diffusion Probabilistic Models by [Sohl-Dickenstein et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03585) and also [Ho et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239) and this [blog post](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models)

1. For the derivation of the model log-likelihood lower bound $K$, my question is why do the authors replace $q(\mathbf{x}^{(t)} | \mathbf{x}^{(t - 1)})$ with $q(\mathbf{x}^{(t-1)} | \mathbf{x}^{(t)}, \mathbf{x}^{(0)})$.  Is there not already an analytic expression for $q(\mathbf{x}^{(t)} | \mathbf{x}^{(t - 1)})$ from the forward diffusion process? Specifically, when the authors go from Equation (46) to Equation (48) they have that

$$K = \sum_{t = 2}^{T} \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}^{0, \ldots, T} q \left( x^{0, \ldots, T}\right) \log \left[ \frac{p(\mathbf{x}^{(t - 1)}|\mathbf{x}^{(t)})}{q(\mathbf{x}^{(t)} | \mathbf{x}^{(t - 1)})}\right] - \text{Other terms}.$$
The authors then use Bayes’ Rule and condition on $\mathbf{x}^{(0)}$ to get the expression in terms of $q(\mathbf{x}^{(t-1)} | \mathbf{x}^{(t)}, \mathbf{x}^{(0)})$

$$K = \sum_{t = 2}^{T} \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}^{0, \ldots, T} q \left( x^{0, \ldots, T}\right) \log \left[ \frac{p(\mathbf{x}^{(t - 1)}|\mathbf{x}^{(t)})}{q(\mathbf{x}^{(t-1)} | \mathbf{x}^{(t)}, \mathbf{x}^{(0)})}\right] - \textrm{More terms}
$$

A similar technique is used in Ho et. al. in going from Equation (18) to Equation (20) and in the blog post in the Reverse Diffusion Process section

2. My second question is why the forward diffusion process is even needed during training?  I get that the authors are maximizing the model log likelihood and they derive a lower bound that depends on both $q(\cdot)$ and $p(\cdot)$

$$L = \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}^{(0)} q \left( \mathbf{x}^{(0)} \right) \log p \left( \mathbf{x}^{(0)}\right)$$

Can we instead maximize based only on the joint probability $p(\cdot)$ as is done with a Markov chain?  Specifically, we can maximize

$$\hat{L} = \prod_{t= 1}^{T} p\left( \mathrm{x}^{(t - 1)} | \mathrm{x}^{(t)}\right)$$

where $p\left( \mathrm{x}^{(t - 1)} | \mathrm{x}^{(t)}\right) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu_\theta}, \mathbf{\Sigma_\theta})$.  Is it that

a) Maximizing $\hat{L}$ solely based on $p(\cdot)$ is also ok but since we have additional information about the forward process in terms of $q(\cdot)$, incorporating this information will help with training

b) It is better to maximize the marginal probability $p \left( \mathbf{x}^{(0)}\right)$ in $L$ instead of the joint probability $\prod_{t= 1}^{T} p\left( \mathrm{x}^{(t - 1)} | \mathrm{x}^{(t)}\right)$ in $\hat{L}$